Dealing with bad responses via Fetch
I have the following code:
function handleSubmit() {
    fetch(`/api/v1/teams`, {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: nameRef.current.value
      }),
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json()
    }).then(data => {
      
    })
  }

which is intended to hit an API endpoint and grab the data in the response (in that last then block).  This is all fine.
However, the endpoint in question sometimes returns a 400 error code, and the JSON in that instance contains the errors.  However, it seems that when I get to that last data block I can no longer read the response.ok.
What would be the ideal way to handle this?

Can you not use async/await syntax? If you're really stuck on .then chaining, note you can resolve with e.g. an object - fetch({ ... }).then((res) => res.json().then((data) => ({ ok: res.ok, data }))). Or if (!res.ok) { throw res } and deal with that JSON in a .catch callback. "Ideal" really depends on your needs.

Why not check the response before desierializing?

next.js - so no use of async/await in a client component

You can't use async/await at the top level of the component, because it has to return the element not the promise of an element, but that syntax is supported - perhaps handleSubmit could be async, for example.

As hinted by @jonsharpe, functions within a client component in Next can use async/await:
async function handleSubmit() {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/v1/teams`, {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: nameRef.current.value
      }),
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    const json = await response.json()
    if (!response.ok) {
      setErrors(json)
    }
  }

